# How to plot a set of points in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of points created through a python program which belongs to different clusters. I would like to plot it on a graph so that points in different clusters should be plotted with different colours.

UPDATE

In my case I have a univariate data ( marks of a test). Looking for a way to plot it.

I have two clusters that are stored in two arrays. Like `x=[1,20,10,4]`, `y=[1644,34444]`. I would like to plot it like as in a cluster

Comment: Can you show what the data looks like and I can suggest the function used to plot

Comment: Hope now the question is clear

Comment: are the points like (1,1644),(20,1644)....(1,34444)....?

Comment: no. x and y are two different clusters

Comment: but for any plot you need a x and y co-ordinate whats the x and whats the y here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). I'm not sure to understand exactly your need, but it could be something like this :

```
from pylab import *
for (x, y) in clusters:
    plot(x, y, '+')
show() # or savefig(<filename>)
```

Comment: Beware, `from ... import *` is not a good practice... Here `from pylab import plot, show` is enough.

Comment: @Emmanuel: no need to take guidelines too literally. `pylab` is that part of matplotlib that was *designed* to be interactive (replacing matlab's plotting), hence `from pylab import *` is a common idiom. It's not really being used in production code - for that you just use the regular matplotlib APIs and classes

Comment: Thanks for the info. It would be helpful if you tell about plotting one dimensional data ( marks in a test )

Answer (score 0):

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is an easy to use plotting library. Should do what you want. Assuming your problem isn't one of the clustering itself, you should be able to use that library for what you want.

I've also had some joy with [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/). It has a steeper learning curve, but has some neat features (if you wanted to interact with the data, for example).

Answer (score 0):

`svg.charts` is a nice module available at [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).